# OKX - API - Demo Trading

Tags: api, trading

OKX api_v5

I can get the following via the api - demo and live:

- Account information
- Coin balance
- Market info
- Candlestick info

I am trying to place a demo order with api.

Error -- The documentation says it's possible to trade via api

```
(
    [clOrdId] => 
    [ordId] => 
    [sCode] => 51010
    [sMsg] => The current account mode does not support this API interface. 
    [tag] => 
)
```

Call

```
[curl_params] => {"instId":"BTC-USDT-SWAP","sz":2,"side":"buy","px":21396.1,"ordType":"limit","tdMode":"isolated","uly":"BTC-USDT"}
[curl_method] => POST
[curl_url] => https://www.okx.com/api/v5/trade/order
```

Extra info - Some of the headers
[5] - just to show the raw signed info

```
[0 - 3] [REMOVED_SIGNED_DETAILS]
[4] => OK-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP: 2022-06-26T01:59:42.614Z
[5] => SIGN: 2022-06-26T01:59:42.614ZPOST/api/v5/trade/order{"instId":"BTC-USDT-SWAP","sz":2,"side":"buy","px":21396.1,"ordType":"limit","tdMode":"isolated","uly":"BTC-USDT"}
[6] => x-simulated-trading: 1
```

Has anyone been able to do the demo trading with the api?

Does anyone see anything wrong with the request?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

swatch trade tab, open settings, you can change account mode from simple to single currency margin